# I want custom entity manager in identity 2.0. How can i do?

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    Startup.DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationCustomManager>(ApplicationCustomManager.Create);
}
```

I Need custom manager code for identity 2.0 in asp.net mvc.

Here i need tenant not for user but i have a table named site. I want site CURD handle by owin context.

I need any example of custom application manager code for any other entity except user and role.

Comment: I'm afraid your question does not contain enough details for anyone to answer. Can you please put a bit more information about your requirements into the question?

Comment: Here i need tenant not for user but i have a table named site. I want site CURD handle by owin context.

Comment: I need any example of custom application manager code for any other entity except user and role.

Comment: What do you mean by "application manager"? Is that `ApplicationDbContext`?

Comment: I need one more Custom manager like ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationRoleManager.

Comment: I am working with multiple dbcontext in identity i have custom table structure but i want to use identity flow for user, role and my another table site. So can i use identity multi tenant functionality for my another table.

Comment: So what does that "custom manager" should do?

Comment: It's work as tenant in my application.

Comment: It's work same as UserManager.